# Java OO main method confusion

Tags: java

So I'm just starting to learn java and have come to this example:

```
class Dog {
    int size;
    String breed;
    String name;

    void bark() {
        System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
    }
} // class Dog

class DogTestDrive {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dog d = new Dog();
            d.size = 40;
            d.bark();
        } // end main
} // class DogTestDrive
```

When I try to run it I get the following error: Error: Main method not found in class Dog, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

I don't see where is the problem? This should work with only one main mathod.

Comment: You have to execute `DogTestDrive`.

Comment: `java DogTestDrive` - not `java Dog`.

Comment: Thank you all for help, it works now, i was a little confused since I'm trying to learn everything without ide, just notepad++ and cmd. This helped me understand things a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start java, you tell it which class to execute. Java finds the `main()` method in the specified class and calls it.

You need to tell java to execute `DogTestDrive`.

Note that if you're executing this in an IDE it's as easy as right-clicking on `DogTestDrive` in your project and chiding "Run".

---

The class java runs must be a "top level" class - that is one that is declared in its own file of the same name as the class, but with `.java` added (not a class declared in another class's file).

Comment: What if he has these in the same file, I believe the file has to be named DogTestDrive

Comment: @svenoaks good point. I didn't think of that... I'll make a note in the answer

Comment: Thank you for help, it helped me a lot. Considering this about same file, yes both of the classes are in the same file but filename doesn't have to be like the name of class it contains. I've tried to name file example.java and it compiles without problems. Also it makes 2 new files, for each class one, and when i run DogTestDrive it runs normal. I don't know if that's what you thought when you wrote "What if he has these in the same file".

Answer (score 1):

Your main method is in the class `DogTestDrive` not the class `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

What Tim B means is that you have to run `DogTestDrive` instead of `Dog`. This way the main method from `DogTestDrive` is used and no main method in `Dog` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, each file with a `.java` extension has one public class with the same name as the file (e.g. `Dog.java` has `public class Dog {...`).  A file can have multiple classes, but only one can be `public`.

When you run a file named `Dog.java`, Java will try to execute `Dog.main` in the file.  If you want `DogTestDrive.main` to run then you must put `DogTestDrive` in `DogTestDrive.java` As for `class Dog {...`, can either go in the same file or in its own `Dog.java` file, the latter being preferred because then classes outside of the file will be able to access it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code runs right, but make sure that the file is named "DogTestDrive.java", because you must run it. Further, you should declare the class DogTestDrive as `public` (not necessary).

```
  class Dog {
        int size;
        String breed;
        String name;

        void bark() {
            System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
        }
    } // class Dog

    public class DogTestDrive {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Dog d = new Dog();
                d.size = 40;
                d.bark();
            } // end main
    } // class DogTestDrive
```

Comment: Having the class `Dog` being public and not in its own compile unit will cause a compilation failure.  Furthermore, there is not requirement in this case for the class `Dog` to be public.

Comment: Omg you're right, I wanted to recommend the use of public when declare a class.